# Not able to get multiple strings output from python script using c#

Tags: c#, python-3.x

I have a richtextbox where I am inserting string value as:- Archit Panda.

But I am getting output from python script as 'Archit' only.

C# code on a  button:-

private void button13_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart,richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
        string str = textRange.Text;
        string FileName = @"C:\Users\Archit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe";
       // string myPythonApp = @"""C:\Users\Archit\Documents\Visual studio 2010\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\blockchain.py""";
        string myPythonApp = @"blockchain.py";
        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FileName);

        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //Console.WriteLine(splitted.ToString());
        myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp+ " " +str;
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
        myProcess.Start(); 
        StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
        string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();

        myProcess.WaitForExit();
        myProcess.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Value received from script: " + myString); 

    }
```

Python script:-

## !/usr/bin/python

import sys

x = sys.argv[1] 
print(x)

I want to get output as 'Archit Panda'.
Can you please tell me what I am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are taking the arguments and you send it "Archit Panda" that will be like sending this to the command line.

`python blockchain.py Archit Panda`

In your Python script you are only looking for argv[1] which is Archit.  argv[2] is Panda.  If you want to pass with arguments in your Python script either loop through them or you can escape the spaces in your C# application and send it something like.  `"Archit\ Panda"` or `"'Archit Panda'"`

Command Line Options

`tmp$ python3 test.py Archit Panda
Archit
tmp$ python3 test.py 'Archit Panda'
Archit Panda
tmp$ python3 test.py Archit\ Panda
Archit Panda
tmp$ python3 test.py 'Archit Panda can send a lot of text to this argument.'
Archit Panda can send a lot of text to this argument.`

If you use quotes replace this line.

`myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp+ " " +str;`

with

`myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp+ " \"" +str+"\"";`

Hope this gets you going.

Comment: Thanks Ben. But my problem is that I can get any number of strings from the richtextbox. It can be any number of lines. I am reading the input into 'str'. How can I deal with this?

Comment: So if you really want to use 1 argument you can either escape the spaces or put the entire thing in quotes. `myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp+ " '" +str + "'";`

Comment: This line:-                                                          
                  myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp + " '" + str + "'";
            Console.WriteLine(myProcessStartInfo.Arguments);       
 gives this:- blockchain.py 'Archit Panda
'                                                                                                                       And output is:- Value received from script: 'Archit

Comment: I tried the replace method and I am able to send the strings as a whole. Thank you.

Comment: I had to switch to my windows machine.  instead of ' use \" .